# Linear selection time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

Hypothetically say that linear selection uses subsequences of size 3 and the worst-case running time is not O(n) anymore. I've come to a conclusion that the time complexity is 3n+T(n/3)+T(2n/3). Now assume that T(n) is equal or smaller than cn. But I can't get for c when I isolate c. They just cancel out each other. Does this happen because it is not cn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You recurrence equation is consistent with `O(n log n)`, and not linear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not so clear why. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @alsrb17 Just repeat the recurrence a bunch of times, and sum the geometric series...